# How to handle switch conditions using java stream API

Tags: java

I am trying to construct sql query based on request. I have different types of expressions:

"and" -> And Expression
"or" -> Or Expression
"eq" -> Equality Expression
"notEq" -> Not Equality Expression
"ge" -> Greater Than Equality Expression
"gt" -> Greater Than Expression
"lt" -> Less Than Expression
"le" -> Less Than Equality Expression
"between" -> Between Expression
"like" -> Like Expression

I have tried for two conditions. But I want to do multiple conditions based on type I have to select expression. Like if `eq` is type then I have expression is `=` or `in` if between type then I have expression like `between`.

```
searchQuery = listOfExpression.stream()
        .map(e -> e.getFilterName() + "" +
                (e.getType(). equalsIgnoreCase("eq") ? " in" : " like") + "(" +
                (e.getValues().stream()
                        .map(s -> "'" + s + "'")
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(","))) + ")")
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" " + searchType));
```

Comment: Well, you could put the switch into the lambda, provide a method that can be called in the lambda or acces some map. Without having a better understanding of what you're trying to achieve it's hard to help. Could you provide some more examples of input and desired output? And could you also explain why you want to use streams for that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Please give an example input and the expected output for it.

Comment: I have below conditions in side stream API map method.     if(e.getType(). equalsIgnoreCase("eq")){
            output="eqexpression";
        }else if(e.getType(). equalsIgnoreCase("and")){
            output="andexpression";
        }else if(e.getType(). equalsIgnoreCase("or")){
            output="orexpression"
        }

Comment: in above expression instead of e.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("eq") ? " in" : " like") I need like below 
     if(e.getType(). equalsIgnoreCase("eq")){
            output="eqexpression";
        }else if(e.getType(). equalsIgnoreCase("and")){
            output="andexpression";
        }else if(e.getType(). equalsIgnoreCase("or")){
            output="orexpression"
        }